# how to use macro definitions that are defined in a headerfile(.h) file in a makefile in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, macros, makefile

I have written certain macros in a headerfile(.h)file. I want those macros to be used in a makefile in linux OS. How can i declare (or) get that macro definitions from a header file in to a makefile.

I have added the file using "-include" in a makefile, but i could not read the macro definitions.

Comment: In which way do you want to use those macros in the makefile? Could you add a sample in your question, that demonstrates what you're actually trying to do? Sounds much like a XY-problem or general misconception for me.

Comment: Not getting exactly what you mean? You can pass symbol during compilation using `-D` option.like `gcc -DMYMACRO .....`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Header files are for C code.